# Is there a minimal TV GUI for youtube-dl & omxplayer on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, youtube-dl, omxplayer

Here's my issue:

My Raspberry Pi boots to console (Raspbian) and does the following:
- Checks a small Youtube-DL script for new updates to a playlist. If so, it pulls the video and copies it to a folder.

- After the video is saved, OMXPlayer plays that video from command line and it works perfectly (on 720p, which is great for my use).

-- That's it. It doesn't do anything else.

Here's the issue. I wanted to create a small GUI where I can scroll through older videos. I don't want to boot to a desktop. I tried an Electron JS app but it creates an entire instance of a web browser - which slows down OMXPlayer for me. I tried to mess around with Python TKinter but it won't let me load the script without first typing "startx" which boots up the Raspbian desktop.

Just want a small GUI (similar to KODI) but without anything else other than videos, and a short interface to scroll through different files.

Any suggestions?